# What does defining the character set affect?

Tags: html, character-encoding

Assume I'm on a computer with character set "a", and browsing a page with character set "b", of which "a" and "b" are wildly different character sets. Specifically the character code for a space in "a" is not a space in "b".

If I type a space into a text input on the page, would the page register it as a space? And, when sent to be processed by the server, would that be processed like a space or another character?

Comment: Bad assumption. The computer would switch to character set "b" when it loaded the page.

Comment: What do you mean bad assumption? That's the situation here. This didn't help me at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignore what character set your computer and server are "on", that doesn't matter. What matters is the character set of the given HTTP request/response. If you request a resource and the server returns character set "B" then your browser will try to parse the response using character set "B". Most browsers are able to parse many different character sets regardless of the underlying computer's current language settings.  If your browser doesn't know about the supplied character set (which would be a rare case, my IE has 34 character sets and my Firefox has 74) then that is [specifically undefined](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/charset.html#h-5.45). It may guess or it might throw an error, its up to the browser to decide.

Many (or possibly most) character sets are partly based on `ASCII` and therefor map the first 127 characters the same way. Even the double-byte [`ISO/IEC 2022`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_2022#Code_structure) does. All HTML tags are based on the `ASCII` set so for these cases the browser might guess at the encoding (some might assume `ISO-8859-1`) so they should be able to render the structure of the document at least. However some encodings, such as the various flavors of [`EBCDIC`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Binary_Coded_Decimal_Interchange_Code) don't map to `ASCII`. In some versions the `EBCDIC` `<` symbol maps to the ASCII `L` symbol, so HTML rendering would completely fail and the raw bytes (probably parsed as ISO-8859-1) would be displayed instead.

So if your browser encounters a `SHIFT_JIS` document but doesn't know how to parse the bytes it will probably attempt to parse it using `ISO-8859-1`. Because the first 127 characters in `SHIFT_JIS` map the same as in `ISO-8859-1` (for the most part), all HTML should render just fine. The text, however, will probably use the browser's "unknown" character which is sometimes a question mark or some form of boxed character. If this document has a form in it and you start typing in it, the keys on your keyboard will be mapped to what the browser is guessing at, which is once again probably `ISO-8859-1`. When you hit submit, those characters will be encoded as the "guessed" character set and be sent to the server as such.

Answer (score 1):

Your browser accepts a couple of encodings, like ISO-8859-1 (Western Latin-1) and UTF-8 (Unicode, the code suitable for all).

The web server gives send a page to the browser.
In the header lines before the HTML source text it normally specifies:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

In HTML it can do the same via .

When the browser presents a page in coding XXX and it submits the form in that encoding, possibly with a specific coding %FC or 纲. This is a POST or GET request to the web server.

The web server has to treat the request as in coding XXX (it no longer has the web page).
This requires deliberate programming, or relying on defaults. Tricky. You should not need to decode %FC and such.

It is a very volatile affair. Please research elsewhere too. I might not have presented all caveats. (For instance there are differences between GET/POST and different browsers.)

Comment: Right but if I'm not using any crazy characters like %FC then there wouldn't be a problem right? Like if they type regular characters (alphanumeric and spaces etc.) then it should be able to go through no problem, right?

Comment: It is almost never safe to assume that all input will be ASCII.